# How many articles are present in my site?

Tags: ee1, count

I'm using EE 1.7.3, and I'd like to know how many articles are present in my site (there are thousands, want an exact number). Where can I find this?

Answer (score 4):

In the control panel go to 
*Admin  ›  Utilities  ›  SQL Manager  ›  Database Query Form*

In the query form put

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exp_weblog_titles;
```

This will give you the total number of entries on your site.

If you would like to know the number of entries in a specific *Weblog* you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exp_weblog_titles
WHERE weblog_id = X;
```

Just replace "X" with the weblog_id of the Weblog you are interested in.

An alternative to running MySQL queries in the control panel is to use an application like [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) or [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/products/navicat-for-mysql) to browse your database and/or run these queries.

---

NOTE for EE v2.x users: alter the SQL by replacing "weblog" with "channel."

Comment: +1, If you want to only count those that are not closed you want to add `AND status != "closed"`